# Spring boot - "Source code doesn't match the bytecode"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, maven

Whenever I try to reload my project in maven, I am redirected to `AopUtils` in `org.springframework.aop.support` package.

I got into this problem after I did some digging when I was trying to save entity in my repository.

```
    public Event addNewEvent(Event event) {
        if (event == null) {
            logger.error("Invalid event!");
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid event!");
        }
        if (eventRepository.existsById(event.getId())) {
            logger.warn("Event with this ID already exists!");
            return event;
        }
        eventRepository.save(event);
        logger.info("Event successfully added!");
        return event;
    }
```

When returning event I got redirected here:

```
    @Nullable
    public static Object invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(@Nullable Object target, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {

        // Use reflection to invoke the method.
        try {
            ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(method);
            return KotlinDetector.isSuspendingFunction(method) ?
                    KotlinDelegate.invokeSuspendingFunction(method, target, args) : method.invoke(target, args);
        }
```

saying that "Source code doesn't match bytecode" and when I downloading source of the class, I was met with 11 errors, one of which was coming from imports - `import kotlin.coroutines.Continuation;` error message was `Cannot resolve symbol 'kotlin'` and I don't even use kotlin in the first place! I use spring boot with maven build system.

Here is what my pom looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: First which Maven version, JDK Version are you using? Second does your build work from plain command line (not from within your IDE)